# Mostrar comentários tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia galera,

Gostaria de saber se é possível eu listar no SQL-SERVER todos os comentários da minha "tabela", não comentários da coluna, mas sim apenas das "tabelas"

Comment: utilize o comando `sp_help [tablename]`

Comment: Eu tentei, mas não trouxe a Extended Properties da tabela

Answer (score 3):

Há algumas formas de obter as propriedades estendidas de uma tabela. Uma delas é através da função [fn_listextendedproperty()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-listextendedproperty-transact-sql):

```
-- código #1
SELECT sys.objects.name as [Nome da tabela], 
       EP.name as [Nome do comentário], 
       EP.value as [Descrição do comentário]
  from sys.objects
  cross apply fn_listextendedproperty(default,
                                    'SCHEMA', schema_name(schema_id),
                                    'TABLE', name, null, null) as EP
  where sys.objects.name not in ('sysdiagrams');
```

O código acima lista todas as propriedades estendidas. Se quiser pode limitar a uma propriedade em específico, acrescentado o filtro na cláusula WHERE.

No tópico [Consulta para selecionar a descrição de uma coluna](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/pt-BR/8f4d4710-75fd-4803-9e64-7e91ddd5b29e/consulta-para-selecionar-a-descrio-de-uma-coluna?forum=520) ela também é utilizada, mas para obter a descrição das colunas.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que inspecionar a tabela do sistema extended_properties

Veja o exemplo:

```
CREATE table Tabela (id int , campo char (20))

EXEC   sp_addextendedproperty 'Descrição', 'ID', 'user', dbo, 'table', 'Tabela', 'column', id

EXEC   sp_addextendedproperty 'Descrição', 'Campo', 'user', dbo, 'table', 'Tabela', 'column', campo
```

Para listar os comentários basta fazer:

```
select * 
from sys.extended_properties 
where NAME = 'Descrição'
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bdb31/1)

Verifique a documentação da tabela [Sys.extended_properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/extended-properties-catalog-views-sys-extended-properties?view=sql-server-2017) para maoires detalhes.

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo script que fiz e retornou:

```
select ob.name,ep.value from sys.extended_properties ep
 inner join sys.objects ob ON ep.major_id=ob.OBJECT_ID AND class=1
 where minor_id = 0 and ob.name not like '%sp%'
```